# How to store values in an ArrayList dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

This is a very basic or rather simple question. 
In my code, I'm using foreach value to put values in a string variable. ***For each iteration I want to store(add one after another) that variable value in an arraylist.*** Then retrieve arraylist values by its index.

Code I'm trying:

```
foreach(string abc in namestring)
{
   string values = abc;
   ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
   list.Add(values);
}
```

For Example:

> If 'namestring' contains values as tom, dik, harry. Then 'list' should
>   contain those  values as list(0) = tom, list(1) = dik, list(2) =
>   harry.

Problem is with storing values in arraylist

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What is editorValue? What exactly is the problem? list.Add() should work fine for adding strings. Although I would recommend using the generic List<string> instead.

Comment: Just curious: Why use `.ToString()` on `abc`, when it's already defined as a `string`?

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand your question, could you perhaps elaborate? You dont have to use toString() on abc. It's already a string.

Comment: @ GAZ, EBB, MARTHIN:  Sorry for the mistakes. I have edited the question. Thnx for the concern and notifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare your `ArrayList` outside the loop:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
foreach(string abc in namestring)
{
   list.Add(abc);
}
```

Also if you are on .NET 2.0 and above you should use the strongly typed `List<string>` instead:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Comment: You should also consider using List<string> instead of ArrayList

Comment: @Broken Glass: Thnx a lot for the solution. declaring arraylist above foreach loop, made my way clear.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` above the foreach

Comment: Aap sahi ho dost. Just declaring arraylist above foreach loop worked. Can't select more than 1 ANSWER, or else u also would have been in there.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create your list before `foreach` loop. Atm you're creating foreach string in collection new list and then forgeting about its reference.

Comment: @Aug: Yup. Declaring arraylist above foreach loop, is correct. Tnx for help. And yes thnx again for explaining the reason also. That was needed to avoid this mistake next time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that your namestring is already a collection (implementing ICollection)... If so you can do it without a loop.

```
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.AddRange(namestring);
        return list;
```

or

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.AddRange(namestring);
        return list;
```

or, simple use the constructor

```
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(namestring);
```

or

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>(namestring);
```

Comment: DKNAAK- thnx for caring to throw lights on so many other effective alternatives. I've got my solution my declaring arraylist above foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new ArrayList();
foreach(string abc in namestring)
{           
    list.Add(abc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code can be fixed moving the "new ArrayList()" line outside of the foreach.

Anyway...

> If 'namestring' contains values as tom, dik, harry. Then 'list' should
>   contain those values as list(0) = tom, list(1) = dik, list(2) = harry

namestring already contains those, as namestring[0] = tom, etc. so you could use it as it is.

Comment: ya alex thanks. I understood the solution, by putting arraylist declaration outside foreach loop.